# PHP PDO::DBLIB, sending query to MS SQL server (wrong encoding?)

Tags: php, pdo

Im using PHP 5.3 on a linux server and I m trying to query a MS SQL Server 2005 database

i ve connected using PDO DBLIB and i can select just fine.
But when i try to enter greek characters in my query, for example:
`where title='χψζ'` the query() returns false , which means it didnt find any rows.

it must be that χψζ is sent to the server in a non 'matching' way, what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found it, i saw it returns on the browser, text encoded as Windows-1253, i thought i have to convert my query to Windows-1253.

using `$query=iconv( 'UTF-8', 'Windows-1253', $query );`

it can now compare χψζ with the one stored in the database.